# gmaps rails ignoring zoom parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does anybody know how to fix this?
Looks like the zoom parameter in the following line is being ignored. I get the same view with the same zoom level every time.
Thanks for any hints.

```
=gmaps("map_options" => { "detect_location" => false, "center_on_user" => false, "zoom" => 9},"markers" => { "data" => @json })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing {} in gmaps method. All your parameters should be enclosed in brackets like this:

```
<%= gmaps({
            "map_options"   => { "detect_location" => false, "center_on_user" => false, "zoom" => 9},
            "markers"       => { "data" => @json } 
    })
%>
```